# The memory consumption of the bind and arrow functions is inconsistent with the theory

Tags: javascript, memory, bind, es6-class, arrow-functions

in es6 class，to bind this(for react event handler)，

use `bind` like this:

```
class BindFn {
    constructor() {
        this.fn = this.fn.bind(this);
    }
    fn() {}
}
```

or use `arrow function` like this:

```
class ArrowFn {
    fn = () => {}
}
```

because bind is implement like this:

```
const bind = function(scope) {
    const fn = this;
    return function(...args) {
        return fn.apply(this, args);
    };
};
```

so when we create multiple instance, use `bind` will reuse reference  in prototype.And use `arrow function` will create  new function without use reference.

And i write a html to test, first use `BindFn` execute ten times, each recording time and max jsHeap in chrome performance. And then `ArrowFn`.
Finally, i got this:

```
use bind:  spend time: 527.2  maxHeap: 173.4M
use arrow: spend time: 1081.2 maxHeap: 174.8M
```

memory use is similar, i thtink  use bind will decrease a lot, why?

my html body code:

```
class BindFn {
    constructor() {
        this.fn = this.fn.bind(this);
    }
    fn() {
        const str = 'sdffsdfsdf'.repeat(999999);
        return str
    }
}
class ArrowFn {
    fn = () => {
        const str = 'sdffsdfsdf'.repeat(999999);
        return str;
    };
}
const objList = [];
let startTime = new Date();
for (let i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
    // objList.push(new BindFn());
    objList.push(new ArrowFn());
}
console.log('spend time:' + (new Date() - startTime));
```

Comment: Note that what you're measuring is something closer to CPU time - memory usage is entirely different. You can also entirely omit the body of the `fn`s if you wish, the output time looks similar.

Answer (score 0):

In both BindFn and ArrowFn you have function created for every instance.

This line creates a fn function for every Bindfn instance:

```
this.fn = this.fn.bind(this);
```